# How can I set App.js as /Home route with React Router?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router to develop my site and the issue I'm running into is that when I switch pages, all the code from /app.js (which contains the homepage code) is loading along with the the new page. For example, I have a contact page and when I load localhost:3000/contact, instead of just the contact page  loading, the homepage is loading as well.

I'm aware that the common fix for this is to load your homepage logic in a separate (/Home) component like so,

`<Route path='/' exact component={Home} />`

however, I didn't build the app with using react router in mind, so I didn't create a /Home component and instead just made the homepage in app.js.

My question is if there is any way to set app.js as the home component in order to use the same method for preventing homepage code from loading along with the other pages, perhaps something like this,

`<Route path='/' exact component={App} />`

(I'm aware this code doesn't run but it's just an example of what I'm looking to accomplish).

I know I'm probably being a hopeless optimist looking for a solution with app.js as the homepage (otherwise why would creating a /Home component be common practice) but I'm holding out on the slim chance that there is a method to do this cause I'm too lazy to restructure the homepage code into another component (but I will if there is really no other choice).

Edit: added app.js jsx/html below

````
return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        
        <div className='heading'>
          <img className='headerImg' src='https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/02/81/78/60/240_F_281786078_SSNSRQp1QBHmbyEciCRGIJutiDj2Y7uq.jpg' alt='bear vs bull'></img>
          <h1 className='header'>Stock Data Search</h1>
          <div className='pageLinks'>  
              <p className='headerLink'>Stock Search</p>
              <a href='#aboutUs' className='headerLink'>About</a>
              <a href='#services'className='headerLink'>Services</a>
              <a href='#contactUs' className='headerLink'>Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id='introduction'>
            <h1 id='introText'>Search the NYSE & NASDAQ<br></br> for stock data and price charts.</h1>
            <h3 id='introLink' ><button id='introButton' type='submit'>Start Searching</button></h3>
        </div>
        <div id='divider'></div>
        <div id='pageJump'></div>
      
        <div id='aboutUs'>
          <h1>About Us</h1>
        </div>
        <div id='services'>
          <h1>Services</h1>
        </div>
        <div id='contactUs'>
          <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        </div>
      
        <form id='form1' className='form1'>
          <p id='tickerInput'>Ticker?<input className='dateSelect' type='text' value={userTickerValue} onChange={handleChangeTickerInput} maxLength='6'></input></p>
          <hr></hr>
          <label htmlFor='timeFrameSelected'>TimeFrame:</label>
          <select id='timeFrameSelected'name='timeFrame'  onChange={handleTimeFrame} defaultValue='TIME_SERIES_DAILY'>
              <option id='Daily' value='TIME_SERIES_DAILY'>Daily</option>
              <option id='Weekly' value='TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY'>Weekly</option>
              <option id='Monthly' value='TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY'>Monthly</option>
          </select>
          <hr></hr>
          <div id='dateContainer'>
            <h3 id='dateHeader'>Date</h3>
            <label htmlFor='yearSelected'>Year</label>
            <input className='dateSelect' id='yearSelected' type='number' onChange={handleYearChange} value={yearValue}  min='1980'max='2021'></input>
            <label htmlFor='monthSelected'>Month</label>
            <input className='dateSelect' id='monthSelected' type='number' onChange={handleMonthChange} value={monthValue}  min='1' max='12'></input>
            <label htmlFor='daySelected'>Day</label>
            <input className='dateSelect' id='daySelected' type='number' onChange={handleDayChange} value={dayValue} min='1' max='31'></input>
          </div>
          <hr></hr>
          {timeFrame === 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY' ? <p id='timeSelect'><input className='timeFrame' type='number' min='1' max='30' value={timeFrames} onChange={handleTimeFrames}></input> {timeFrames > 1 ? 'days' : 'day'} of data.</p> : timeFrame === 'TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY' ? <p><input className='timeFrame' type='number' min='1' max='24' defaultValue='1' value={timeFrames} onChange={handleTimeFrames}></input>{timeFrames > 1 ? 'Weeks' : 'Week'} of data.</p> : timeFrame === 'TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY' ? <p><input className='timeFrame' type='number' min='1' max='36' defaultValue='1' value={timeFrames} onChange={handleTimeFrames}></input>{timeFrames > 1 ? 'Months' : 'Month'} of data.</p>:null}
          <input id='submitInput' type='submit' value='Enter' onClick={handleFormSubmit}/>
        </form>
     
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact></Route> 
          <Route path='/StockSearch' exact component={StockSearch}>
            <StockSearch userTickerValue={userTickerValue} tickerData={tickerData} timeFrame={timeFrame} useTickerVal={useTickerVal}></StockSearch>
          </Route>
        </Switch>    
      </div>
    </Router>
   
  ); ```
````

Comment: The problem I can see is that usually your react router logic will be a `child` of App, so you'd end up in an infinite render loop. App renders router, router renders App etc... If this isn't how your app tree looks, you could definitely pass App as a component to your `Route`. Your best bet is probably a simple refactor. Without seeing more code, this is the best answer I can give.

Comment: I added the app html code, one thing to note, me including the contact page when explaining my problem was just an example to be easy to relate to, the actual page I need to load separately is the /StockSearch component, just to clear up any confusion.  Thanks for clearing up the infinite loop issue, I'll probably just end up refactoring the code into a Home component.

Comment: In your `Route` for `/stocksearch` you are using both the component prop and children, which I believe will overwrite each other. You don't have to extract anything, but it will greatly increase your readability. I would recommend making a `Layout` component to hold everything you want on every page, wrap that around your `Switch` so it doesn't update on page changes. Then you can actually move your page content into the `Children` of the `<Route path="/">YOUR STUFF HERE</Route>` and it should work ok.

Comment: I just refactored everything into a Home component and it seems to be working well, I'll have to look more into a wrapping Layout component but for now (seeing as this is my first time using react-router) I'm just glad that I have everything functioning, but like I said, I'll definitely look into using a Layout component in the future. Thanks again for everything, was stuck because of that infinite loop for a good couple of days.